# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails Error

Tags: php, mysql

My code is:

```
private function get_parameters_to_array()
{
    $data = array(
        'datahora' => $this->input->post('datahora'),
        'valor' => $this->input->post('valor'),
        'idProduto' => $this->input->post('idProduto'),
        'idFuncionario' => $this->input->post('idFuncionario'),
        'idMesa' => $this->input->post('idMesa')
    );
    return $data;
}
```

I need to convert the 3 ID values to Int, how to do that? The error I'm getting is this one:

> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`tucunaredb`.`pedido`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Pedido_Funcionario1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`idFuncionario`) REFERENCES `funcionario` (`id`) ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
>
> INSERT INTO `Pedido` (`datahora`, `valor`, `idProduto`,
>   `idFuncionario`, `idMesa`, `ativo`) VALUES ('2016-02-24 23:14:16',
>   '6.50', '8', '5', '2', 1)

Comment: If the DB column is INT then it will be an INT.  But for the record `(int)$this->input->post('idMesa')`

Comment: you can use `(int) $this->etc` but sql will do that for you

Comment: @AbraCadaver thanks, that worked! But I'm still getting the error, must be something else...

Comment: I see you edited.  That's entirely different.

Comment: @AbraCadaver any ideas about that?

Comment: @Xorifelse That's not true of course. If the foreign key would have a unique constraint, it's not possible to create 1:N relations.

Comment: @MickJaggerr BTW it's good idea to specify what particular database are you using when asking something database specific.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy I'm sorry, tired I guess. Assuming this is a child table referring to the primary table column id and its failing with this error it could also be that the primary key is missing. In this case, a removed product.

Comment: @MickJaggerr That's fine. BTW that's exactly what I'm describing in my answer - he's missing a record in the parent table he's referencing to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple and it's exactly what's the error saying: the value you're trying to insert into the column `idFuncionario` which has a foreign key to `funcionario.id` is wrong. You probably don't have any record with `id` 5 in the parent table `funcionario`.

You have to create such record first, then you can reference it from other tables.

The point of [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) is to maintain [the referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity), in other words, *data consistency*.

You have the foreign key `fk_Pedido_Funcionario1` on the column `Pedido.idFuncionario` which references to the column `funcionario.id`. That means you can't have a different value in the `Pedido.idFuncionario` than are values in the `funcionario.id` and the database is checking that. When you're trying to insert a different value, it throws the error you got.

The only other allowed value is `NULL`, but only in a case column can contain such value (is not defined with `NOT NULL`).

Comment: I think that is what is happening, but I don't know why, the same code is working but just for some of the funcionario cadastred, anyway, is working, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "*the same code is working but just for some of the funcionario cadastred*". If by the "code" you mean your `INSERT` then of course, as I explained it depends on values. You can't insert into the column `Pedido.idFuncionario` any value, which **is not** in the column `funcionario.id`.